# Sidekiq trying to connect to Redis even if 'sidekiq/testing' is required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

Ruby version: 3.1.3
Rails version: 7.0.4
Sidekiq / Pro / Enterprise version(s): Standard

**sidekiq.rb initializer**

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true
require "sidekiq"
require "sidekiq-status"

redis_config = {
  url: "#{ENV["REDIS_URL"]}/#{REDIS_SIDEKIQ_DB}"
}

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = redis_config

  Sidekiq::Status.configure_client_middleware config, expiration: 30.minutes.to_i
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = redis_config

  Sidekiq::Status.configure_server_middleware config, expiration: 30.minutes.to_i
  Sidekiq::Status.configure_client_middleware config, expiration: 30.minutes.to_i
end
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```rb
...
 require 'sidekiq-status/testing/inline'

  config.before(:each) do
    Sidekiq::Worker.clear_all
  end
```

my_file_spec.rb

```rb
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe ExpirationCartJob, type: :job, focus: true do
  it { should be_retryable(false) }

  it { should respond_to(:perform) }
  it "should be able to enqueue a job" do
    expect { described_class.perform_async }.to enqueue_sidekiq_job
  end
end
```

**Full backtrace**

```
2023-08-24T16:36:54.153Z pid=80056 tid=1kx0 INFO: Sidekiq 7.1.2 connecting to Redis with options {:size=>10, :pool_name=>"internal", :url=>"/2"}                        |  ETA: 00:00:01

  1) ExpirationCartJob should be able to enqueue a job
     Failure/Error: expect { described_class.perform_async }.to enqueue_sidekiq_job

     ArgumentError:
       Invalid URL: "/2"
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/redis-client-0.16.0/lib/redis_client/url_config.rb:16:in `initialize'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/redis-client-0.16.0/lib/redis_client/config.rb:165:in `new'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/redis-client-0.16.0/lib/redis_client/config.rb:165:in `initialize'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/redis-client-0.16.0/lib/redis_client.rb:144:in `new'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/redis-client-0.16.0/lib/redis_client.rb:144:in `config'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/sidekiq-7.1.2/lib/sidekiq/redis_client_adapter.rb:52:in `initialize'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/sidekiq-7.1.2/lib/sidekiq/redis_connection.rb:21:in `new'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/sidekiq-7.1.2/lib/sidekiq/redis_connection.rb:21:in `create'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/sidekiq-7.1.2/lib/sidekiq/config.rb:140:in `new_redis_pool'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/sidekiq-7.1.2/lib/sidekiq/config.rb:134:in `local_redis_pool'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/sidekiq-7.1.2/lib/sidekiq/config.rb:128:in `redis_pool'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/sidekiq-7.1.2/lib/sidekiq/job.rb:368:in `build_client'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/sidekiq-7.1.2/lib/sidekiq/job.rb:361:in `client_push'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/sidekiq-7.1.2/lib/sidekiq/job.rb:198:in `perform_async'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/sidekiq-7.1.2/lib/sidekiq/job.rb:286:in `perform_async'
     # ./spec/sidekiq/expiration_cart_job_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-sidekiq-4.0.1/lib/rspec/sidekiq/matchers/enqueue_sidekiq_job.rb:23:in `matches?'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-expectations-3.12.3/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:51:in `block in handle_matcher'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-expectations-3.12.3/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:27:in `with_matcher'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-expectations-3.12.3/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:48:in `handle_matcher'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-expectations-3.12.3/lib/rspec/expectations/expectation_target.rb:65:in `to'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-expectations-3.12.3/lib/rspec/expectations/expectation_target.rb:139:in `to'
     # ./spec/sidekiq/expiration_cart_job_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:263:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:263:in `block in run'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:511:in `block in with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:468:in `block in with_around_example_hooks'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:486:in `block in run'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:626:in `block in run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:352:in `call'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-rails-6.0.3/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:390:in `execute_with'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:628:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:352:in `call'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/webmock-3.18.1/lib/webmock/rspec.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:390:in `execute_with'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:628:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:352:in `call'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:629:in `run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:486:in `run'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:468:in `with_around_example_hooks'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:511:in `with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:259:in `run'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:646:in `block in run_examples'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:642:in `map'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:642:in `run_examples'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:607:in `run'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:121:in `block (3 levels) in run_specs'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:121:in `map'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:121:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:2070:in `with_suite_hooks'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:116:in `block in run_specs'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:74:in `report'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:115:in `run_specs'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:89:in `run'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/bin/rspec:25:in `load'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/bin/rspec:25:in `<main>'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
     # /Users/mateo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
```

I've already setup in the same way in another project, and it works fine. But in this one, for some reason it's trying to connect to Redis when also the docs say it shouldn't.

As per docs, requiring 'sidekiq/testing' should avoid to call Redis.